# How do I get spec matchers to work with my tests? currently, I get a bunch of "already defined" errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

At the top of test_helper.rb

```
require File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + "/../config/environment")

require 'test_help'
require "bundler/setup"
Bundler.require(:test)

require 'spec'
require 'spec/spec_helper'
require 'factory_girl'
require 'shoulda'
require "shoulda-matchers"
require 'spec/expectations'


require 'test/shared_test.rb'
require 'test/attribute_sets.rb'
require 'test/functional/api/visibility_tests'
require 'test/functional/api/common_actions_tests'
require "json"
```

but hen I include spec/spec_helper, all my shoulda checks for relationships get defined twice... and then none of the tests run.

Spec/spec_helper:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'..','config','environment'))
require 'spec/autorun'
require 'spec/rails'
require 'webrat'

Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each {|f| require f}
Dir[File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__),'support','**','*.rb'))].each {|f| require f}
```

Example Error:   * WARNING: 'test: Account should have many users. ' is already defined

But the execution of the `bundle exec rake test:units` command stops when it starts running the actual tests. (same error as the shoulda-warnings)

Note: this is how you get it to work in script/console:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 2.3.8)
>> require "spec"
=> []
>> include Spec::Matchers
=> Object
>> nil.should be_nil
=> true
>>
```

but when I do

```
require 'spec'
include Spec::Matchers
```

in test helper, I get the following error:

```
.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/lib/ruby/1.8/optparse.rb:314:in `initialize': unhandled exception
```

Comment: Just an idea (so not an answer... yet) - try removing the require  shoulda's  I'm not sure if they're needed or if rspec will let you... oh r u not using rspec? Sorry.  Though that would help too.

Comment: hmm. commenting out the shoulda thinsg didn't do anything. also, I'm not sure if i'm 'using' rspec... it's my gemfile... but I just have no idea what is going on anymore =\

Comment: I believe you're not using rspec as you have no gem for it.  You may wish to add it and to start using it as I think you will find much of the most useful documentation on testing is about using rspec

Comment: It's included in the gemfile.... but I've had so many conflicts with my environment, at this point, I feel like the best thing is just to remove everything that doesn't work, and find an alternative way to do it. =\